# Is the symmetric tensor product of hermitian positive semidefinite matrices also hermitian positive semidefinite?

Tags: tensor-products, positive-semidefinite

Let $V = S^{n-1}(\mathbb{C}^2)$ be the $n-1$ th symmetric tensor power of $\mathbb{C}^2$. Thus $V = \mathbb{C}^n$ as a complex vector space. Suppose there given a matrix $A$ of the form

$A = A_1 \odot \cdots \odot A_{n-1}$,

where each $A_i$ is an Hermitian $2$ by $2$ matrix which is positive semidefinite, and the symmetric tensor product $\odot$ is over $\mathbb{C}$.

Question: is $A$ also hermitian positive semidefinite?

As a remark, it is clear that for any

$v = S^{n-1}(\psi)$

for some $\psi \in \mathbb{C}^2$, we have

$v^* A v \geq 0$. But this is as far as I got.

Comment: Doesn't this follow immediately from $A\otimes B$ being Hermetian psd if $A$ and $B$ are?

Comment: Hmm, is it that trivial? Let me think for a moment.

Comment: yes, this is true! Thank you @kimchilover!